# ASP.NET MVC email registration confirmation enters spam folder

Tags: asp.net, gmail

I am using the default ASP.NET `AccountController` any idea why the confirmation mail is entering spam folder in my gmail? the app is configured to send from gmail account

```
//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //  Comment the following line to prevent log in until the user is confirmed.
            //  await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);


            string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Currency Protector - Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account, you must be confirmed "
                                    + "before you can log in.";

            return View("Info");
       }
       AddErrors(result);
   }

   // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
       return View(model);
   }
```

**EDIT**

Here is my mail class

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("XXX@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add(message.Destination);
        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXX@gmail.com", "PASS");

        return smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
  }
```

Comment: Your code really doesn't have anything to do with how Gmail classifies things as spam.

Comment: thanks mason, so still why is it entering spam folder? one of my clients told me that

Comment: I couldn't tell you. Has nothing to do with programming. You might try asking on Super User or researching how Google classifies spam.

Comment: What is your from email, a donotreply account right?  Or what?  Also, change the verbiage of your message to be more like a personal message; it may see the format of the message and naturally think it's spam.